# root.findall doesn't return anything on XML parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml file using Python through `root.findall`.

Basically my file looks like this - and I'm trying to access elements under "Level3".

**Edit:** @trincot, already provided solution.....but, **Now, I've added namespace to the sample data(xmlns="http://xyz.abc/forms"), which is causing the trouble. Why would adding 'xmlns=' cause the issue ? :O**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xyz.abc/forms" xmlns:abc="http://bus-message-envelope" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" abc:version="1-2">
    <env:Header>
        <abc:col1>col1Text</abc:col1>
        <abc:col2>col2Text</abc:col2>
        <abc:col3>col3Text</abc:col3>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <Level1>
            <Level2 schemaVersion="1-1">
                <Level3>
                    <cell1>cell1Text</cell1>
                    <cell2>cell2Text</cell2>
                    <cell3>cell3Text</cell3>
                    <cell4>cell4Text</cell4>
                </Level3>
            </Level2>
        </Level1>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Trying this, but doesn't return anything :**

```python
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse("/tmp/test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for form in root.findall(".//Level3"):
 print(form.text)
 print("Inside Loop") --> Not even hitting this
```

Expected Output:

```
cell1Text
cell2Text
cell3Text
cell4Text
```

**I was able to access the same elements through code below**. But, how to achieve this using `findall`?

```python
for x in root[1][0][0][0]:
 print(x.text)
```

Output:

```
cell1Text
cell2Text
cell3Text
cell4Text
```

I did go through most of Stack Overflow, but couldn't get an answer to this. Tried many things but failed :( .

Comment: This is out of my wheelhouse, but FWIW, you should make a [mre] with complete code. I'm wondering how you created `root` exactly.

Comment: Oops ! added the code on how I've created the root.

Comment: That update changes everything.  See duplicate links for how to account for namespaces in your XPath expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet you access `form.text`, but `form` corresponds to the `Level3` element which has no other text than just white space. The actual text you want to output is sitting in its child nodes. So `print(form.text)` prints white space only.

The working code *iterates* the children of that same `Level3` element:

```
for x in root[1][0][0][0]:
    print(x.text)
```

Here `x` is the *deeper* `cellX` element, which *does* have the text you expect.

To achieve this with `findall` do:

```
for x in root.findall(".//Level3/*"):
    print(x.text)
```

Note the extra level `/*` in the argument of `findall`, which means: any child element of `Level3` elements.

See both the original and corrected code run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq733377665459839#main.py)

If you didn't get *any* output with the first version, then please check spelling. It looks suspicious that the Elements in your XML sometimes start with a capital (like `Level3`) and sometimes not (like `cell1`). This could be a reason of not getting output. However, I loaded your code and XML as-is, and it produced the message "Inside Loop", as you can see when you follow the link above.

Comment: Good, +1, but how do you account for `print("Inside Loop") --> Not even hitting this`?

Comment: I cannot account for that, as I cannot reproduce that problem, @kjhughes. I have added a link to `repl.it` where the asker can see for themselves that the output is generated in their first version of the code.

Comment: Right, I couldn't see how that line would not have been executed either.  Thanks.

Comment: `Level3` in the sample has a text node: `\n     `. Try `print("Text: '" + form.text + "'")`

Comment: @LMC, yes, you are right -- I should say it doesn't have text other than white space. Updated.

Comment: In fact, if indenting is removed (all in one line) the OP should get at `print("Text: '" + form.text + "'")` -> `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`.

Comment: @LMC, could be, but that would be a kind of *output* still -- while they say they get no output. I put my bet on a spelling mistake (in their actual code or XML) whereby `findall` doesn't find anything and the loop does not iterate.

Comment: @trincot : Excellent answer, however while mocking the sample data, found that I've missed another major culprit. When I add namespace like xmlns="http://xyz.abc/forms" , the same code doesn't work again. Updated the sample data in the qsn. Appreciate your help, wonder what could be the issue when the namespace is added !!

Comment: Adding a default namespace to an element effectively changes the element names of the element and all of its descendants that are not otherwise in a namespace.  Namespaced-names have to be accounted for in XPath.  See duplicate links for how.